# OpsHub Migration of source code only from TFS 2010 to Visual Studio Online

Tags: azure-devops, opshub

When we started migration of source code the migration utility found 12500 changesets/labels.
In round about 24 hours 207 of this 12500 are indicated as passed.

What is your feeling? Does something go wrong?

Do you have a proposal on how to speed up the process?

Thank you in advance.

Regards,
Andi

Comment: Hi Andi.Do you have a lot of TFS Created Labels (Build Labels)??? Are you looking to have them migrated? Additionally, do send us your logs located at "C:\Program Files\OpsHub Visual Studio Online Migration Utility\logs" so that we can analyze and segregate which process (Getting Files from source, processing or handing over to VSO) is taking time.

Comment: Hello. Great to get your support immediately!!
We do not have many Labels but the large number of Changesets.
Do you need all the logs located - or do you need special subset?
How shall we send the logs to you?
Thank you.
Regards,
Andi

Comment: Yes. All of them please at ovsmu@opshub.com

Comment: Hi.
We are going to prepare the logs to send it to you soon.

Comment: Please give us your opinion to our migration setup:

1. TFS 2010 runs on a system with Intel Xeon CPU E5520, 2,27 GHz, 4 GB Ram, OS MS Windows Server 2003 Standard Edition Service Pack 2.
Performance is very good for our work locally and remote.

2. OpsHub Visual Studio Online Migration Utility runs on a system wthin the same intra network with Intel Core i3-2100 CPU 3,1 GHz, 8 GB Ram, MS OS Windows 7 Prof 64-bit Service Pack 1.

3. Visual Studio Online Datacenter located in Amsterdam, Europa.

4. Our location is in Germany, Europa.

What do you feel about this setup?

Regards,
Andi

Comment: Hello.

As requested by you find the logfiles in your email box ovsmu@opshub.com.
We hope that you can provide a good solution to us.

Thank you for your effort.

Regards,

Andi

Comment: Hello. Till now 337 changesets/labels of 12500 are passed in round about 48 hours. Assumed the time for import is linear the complete import would take round about 75 days!?

Comment: Hello.
We observed the machine running the Migration Utility.
Remarkable is that the traffic of the Gbit-network connection is very low under 0,5%. CPU usage is average 10%.
Did you assess the log-files?
Regards,
Andi

Comment: Hello all.
The migration process is still running.
Currently 869 of 12500 changesets/labels are passed.
We hope that you can provide an applicable solution soon.
Do you have results from the log-file assessment?
Tell us if we can support you.
Regards,
Andi

Comment: Hi Andi, we are analyzing your logs. We'll communicate through mail. Regards, OpsHub Support

Answer (score 0):

Update from OpsHub.

We have done major performance improvements in the current release. It would be available for public download from the Visual Studio Gallery page